# CSS: Image sticking to the bottom right hand side of the document

Tags: html, css

I have a peculiar problem, which I think that a lot of other people have had before, but I'm not so sure there is a good (pure CSS) solution to it...

I have a document with the following structure:

- TOP: 100% wide, 200px high
- MIDDLE: 100% wide, variable height
- BOTTOM: 100% wide, 200px high

BOTTOM is essentially a background image which should stick to the bottom right hand side corner of the browser window *at all times*. However, I don't want to use `absolute` positioning relative to the body of the document, because then it will flow under the text which is in MIDDLE.

So basically I want the same effect as the one I would get using absolute positioning, but I don't want text or other elements to sort of flow over it. It should behave just as if it didn't have any particular positioning, with width 100% and height 200px, *but always in the bottom right hand side of the document*.

I'll be glad to answer any questions about this problem, as I'm sure you won't understand this. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC 
  "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test bottom right fixture</title>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body{margin: 0;}
    #top,#middle,#bottom{width:100%;}
    #top,#bottom{height:200px;}
    #middle{padding-bottom: 200px;}
    #bottom{position: fixed;right:0;bottom:0;}
    .red{background-color: red;}
    .green{background-color: green;}
    .blue{background-color: blue;}
    </style>
    <body>
    <div id="top" class="red">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <div id="middle" class="green">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <div id="bottom" class="blue">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works with both short middle content as shown, or more verbose middle content like Lorem ipsum.

There is an issue where if the page height is higher than 3*200px+middleContentHeight you will see a white gap between the green and blue blocks. This is easily fixed by declaring a background-color for body.

Answer (score 20):

This is a very common issue. solution: position: fixed. This does what you said, makes sure the item ALWAYS appears in a certain position. Use

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;
```

So the  will always appear in the bottom right. idk if you can do this with a background image, but this meets your requirements. its not supported in IE 6 (but then again, what is?). see [here for an example](http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/213/213.css&page=0). scroll up and down the page. Notice how the image is always in at the bottom of the browser window. Also make sure your z-index is adequately large if you don't want things to flow over it. :D

Comment: For use with a background-image use (in addition to other background properties) 'background-attachment: fixed' (it works in FF2+, and I think Webkit, but I don't know about IE).

Comment: This answer has been up-voted a lot, but it is actually not the answer to my original question that I asked about a year ago. What I asked was for the element to stick to the bottom right hand side of the *document* whereas fixed positioning makes the position relative to the *viewport*.

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src="beta.jpg" class="specialImage" />

.specialImage{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:100; /* or higher/lower depending on other elements */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, use the following CSS to get it in the right hand side and always at the bottom:

```
.bottom{
   position: relative;
   bottom: 0;
   float: right;
}
```

Is that what what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer by @stevedbrown:

```
.bottom { z-index: 2; }
```

where 2, is just a higher z-index than the other page elements

Answer (score 0):

I just played around with embedding the image within the text.

More specifically, I was using  the CKEditor and just dragged the image to where I wanted it to be.  Then, I looked at the source to find the image tag was simply moved to some apparently arbitrary location within the div element.

```
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <img src="sunset.jpg" style="position:relative;float:right; padding:3px;" />per seacula futurum.</div>
```

I realize this is not mathematically precise.  But hopefully this solution provides another perspective, at least, to the other answers - (which I could not get to work for me).  There seems to be nothing in CSS that pushes an element to "bottom, right" of a para while having text wrap around.